# C++ write to file error with full PATH from GetEnvironmentVariable()

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, environment-variables

I'm noob in C++ but wanting to learn. I have a little program that writes some info to my `\etc\hosts` in Windows; I get the `%WINDIR%` variable via `GetEnvironmentVariable()`, if I put the full path manually everything is ok, but when I substitute with `WINDIR` variable my code isn't compiling. I know I don't do something right.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <ios>
#include <fstream>

char buffer[1000];
int main() {
    GetEnvironmentVariable("WINDIR",(char*)&buffer,sizeof(buffer));
    std::ofstream log;
    log.open("%s\\system32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts", buffer);
    log << "127.0.0.1   domain.com\n" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get really ugly errors like:

> C:\Documents and Settings\xtmtrx\Desktop\coding\windir.cpp no matching function for call to ``std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(const char[30], char[1000])`'

Comment: `std::ofstream`'s constructor is not a call to `sprintf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ofstream` cannot format the path for you. You need to do that separately, eg:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <ios>
#include <fstream>

char buffer[1000] = {0};
int main() {
    GetEnvironmentVariable("WINDIR",buffer,sizeof(buffer));
    strcat(buffer, "\\system32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts");
    std::ofstream log;
    log.open(buffer, ios_base::ate);
    log << "127.0.0.1   domain.com\n" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

FYI, you should use `GetWindowsDirectory()`, `GetSystemDirectory()`, `SHGetSpecialFolderPath()` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` instead of `GetEnvironmentVariable()`.  And you should use `PathCombine()` when concantenating paths together so it can ensure the slashes are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to concate the string together like this:

```
LPTSTR windir[MAX_PATH];
LPTSTR fullpath[MAX_PATH];
GetWindowsDirectory(windir, MAX_PATH);
if(PathCombine(fullpath, windir, _T("system32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts")) != NULL) {
    std::ofstream log;
    log.open(buffer, ios_base::ate);
    log << "127.0.0.1   domain.com\n" << std::endl;
}
```

At first you need to concate the directory and the file part with [PathCombine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773571.aspx). Then you can open the file and write the content. You should also note that you need admin permissions to change this file and some antivirus programmes may reject the access of the hosts file.

Comment: I think should work but now I get "C:\Dev-Cpp\include\string.h too few arguments to function `void* memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t)'"

Comment: I exchanged the function this should work better and is safer too.

Comment: What is the header file that provides "PathCombineW()" function? Because I get "undeclared" error on it.

Comment: Try to obmit the W. I should compile the code first before answering^^

Comment: Tried with PathCombine and got the same error, I know is an include for sure.

Comment: You are right it is `Shlwapi.h` and also the lib `Shlwapi.lib`. I changed the code a little to support unicode.

Answer (score 1):

`open("%s\\system32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts", buffer);`  open doesn't understand format strings..you are using `%s` does not make sense. learn [here](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=51509)

Try like this:

```
GetEnvironmentVariable("WINDIR",buffer,sizeof(buffer));
strcat(buffer, "\\system32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts");
std::ofstream log;
log.open(buffer.str().c_str(), ios_base::ate);
```